# Android - Best implementation to have a sync data mechanism

Tags: android, android-service, scheduled-tasks

I need to have a sync data mechanism, for that, the idea is to have a service that runs between a time interval to check if there are date to sync and send the information to a server.

For that, what is the best approach? Has a Android Service runs and inside have a Scheduler? Only have a Scheduler? Or another better way?

Comment: I think this is opinion based question. OP have you tried searching on SO? I think if you search for SyncAdapter you will get your answer.

Comment: I searched for some ways to implement that i want. I implemented with ScheduledExecutorService that basically in time interval launch a IntentService to do the sync data. The reason for my question is to see if this is a good implementation or are there better approaches.

Comment: is this a full sync? I mean some data you will get from server and some send to server.

Comment: No, only to send data to server. Basically the idea is you can work offline and in a time interval you sync the local data to server.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Timer class for this and schedule it to run after a specified interval of time. This class is specific for the requirement you have.
check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html and create a TimerTask and SCHEDULE it to fire at whatever interval you feel like. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should instead use `SyncAdapter` to implement sync on android.